# How to fix 'read QR codes Model 1'

Tags: android

I'm coding Andriod studio for reading QRcode with zxing library but when I scan QRcode model 1, it can't detect QRcode.

Others barcode are detected and read normally.

```
    btn_scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {

            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator=new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
            scanIntegrator.setPrompt(" Scan a QR Code");
            scanIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
            scanIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
            scanIntegrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
            //scanIntegrator.setScanningRectangle(450, 450);//size
            scanIntegrator.setCameraId(0);
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It may help to [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57451591/edit) your question with an image of the QR code you are having problems with.

Comment: Morrison Chang ,  I update picture as also discussed.

Comment: Did you see: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/1067

Comment: Morrison Change , you can suggest other solution or  library solve this problem

Comment: Last post in the github issue thread links to fork which supports QR Code Model 1.

Comment: Morrison Change , thank you for suggesting, yes I see source code in the Github, but I don't understand how to use them, I need the sample, please.

Comment: The ZXing library is free open-source and has build instructions in the project. Once built you can replace the ZXing library you are currently using with the fork version that handles QR Code Model 1. Or you can look for a different library (paid/free) which can suit your needs. Asking for tutorials is considered **off-topic**. Good luck.

Comment: Morrison Chang, thank you for good suggestion, I'm trying finding to buy commercial version but don't support QR Code Model 1, you can tell me commercial library support this one to me, my project is large.